# What causes my numbers to go to insane values?

Tags: c

Just making an intentionally repetitive if statement program for spare change, but for an unknown reason it shoots numbers that are supposed to be 0 to some max values? I would really like some help here as to why

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   int d;
   int e;
   int cha;
   
   scanf("%d", &cha);
   
   if(cha == 0){
      printf("No change\n");
      return 0;
   }   
   if(cha >= 100){
      a = cha / 100;
      cha = cha % 100;
   }
   if(100> cha && cha >= 25){
      b = cha / 25;
      cha = cha % 25;
   }
   if(25 > cha && cha >= 10){
      c = cha / 10;
      cha = cha % 10;
   }
   if(10 > cha && cha >= 5){
      d = cha / 5;
      cha = cha % 5;
   }
   if(5 > cha && cha >= 1){
      e = cha;
   }
   if(a == 1){
      printf("%d Dollar\n",a);
   }
   if(a > 1){
      printf("%d Dollars\n",a);
   }
   if(b == 1){
      printf("%d Quarter\n",b);
   }
   if(b > 1){
      printf("%d Quarters\n",b);
   }
   if(c == 1){
      printf("%d Dime\n",c);
   }
   if(c > 1){
      printf("%d Dimes\n",c);
   }
   if(d == 1){
      printf("%d Nickle\n",d);
   }
   if(d > 1){
      printf("%d Nickles\n",d);
   }
   if(e == 1){
      printf("%d Penny\n",e);
   }
   if(e > 1){
      printf("%d Pennies\n",e);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Below is an example as to what gets produced

Input

```
45
```

Your output

```
1 Quarter
2 Dimes
****875483616** Nickles**
**32766 Pennies**
```

Expected output

```
1 Quarter
2 Dimes
```

Comment: Read your warnings.

Comment: none of your values are initialized. `d`, for instance, is only set to a value `if(10 > cha && cha >= 5)`. If that line doesn't hit, `d` has an indeterminate value .. in your specific case, 875483616. That's bigger than 1, so it prints.

Comment: Your variables a to e are _uninitialized_ (i.e. they have "random" values to start). As others have mentioned, with sufficient warning levels, these would be flagged by the compiler. To get _consistent_ values (but maybe _not_ correct) do: `int a = 0; int b = 0; int c = 0; int d = 0; int e = 0;`

Comment: Side note: get into the habit now of using more descriptive variable names. For example: `dollars` instad of `a`.

Comment: One little trick to simplify your printing code is: `printf("%d Dollar%s\n", a, a == 1 ? "" : "s");` -- here, you output a string for the plural part of the word, which is empty if `a` is equal to 1, or `"s"` otherwise. Similarly, you could also write: `printf("%d %s\n", a, a == 1 ? "Dollar" : "Dollars");`

Comment: Expanding on this, you can avoid repetition of logic and hard-coded values by representing your denominations as an array. This makes the code easier to read, and much less prone to mistakes: https://godbolt.org/z/hnaWjncs5

Comment: It would also be a good idea to check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: Thank you, and apologies for not commenting right away. Based on your responses i was able to fix it, thank you! Also apologies it was my first post and i realize that i made mistakes posting it

Answer (score 5):

To consolidate comments, your variables are uninitialized, and your conditions do not lead to them all being initialized before they're printed. You can avoid this simply by initializing those variables to `0`.

```
int main(void) {
   int a = 0;
   int b = 0;
   int c = 0;
   int d = 0;
   int e = 0;
   int cha = 0;

   // ...
```

But you should also use more descriptive names.

```
int main(void) {
   int dollars = 0;
   int quarters = 0;
   int dimes = 0;
   int nickels = 0;
   int pennies = 0;
   int change = 0;
```

And check the return value from `scanf` to ensure it read a value and that it's greater than or equal to zero.

```
int main(void) {
   int dollars = 0;
   int quarters = 0;
   int dimes = 0;
   int nickels = 0;
   int pennies = 0;
   int change = 0;

   if (scanf("%d", &change) != 1 || change < 0) {
      printf("Invalid input.\n");
      return 1;
   }
```

It's important to not repeat yourself when writing a program, so you can loop over arrays.

```
#define NUM_COINS 5

int main(void) {
   char *singular_coin_names[] = {
      "dollar", "quarter", "dime",
      "nickel", "penny"
   };

   char *plural_coin_names[] = {
      "dollars", "quarters", "dimes",
      "nickels", "pennies"
   };

   int coin_values[] = { 100, 25, 10, 5, 1 };
   int change_amounts[NUM_COINS] = {0};
   int change;

   if (scanf("%d", &change) != 1 || change < 0) {
      printf("Invalid input.\n");
      return 1;
   } 

   for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_COINS; i++) {
      if (change == 0) {
         change_amounts[0] = 0;
      }
      else {
         change_amounts[i] = change / coin_values[i];
         change %= coin_values[i];
      }
   }

   for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_COINS; i++) {
      printf(
         "%d %s\n",
         change_amounts[i],
         change_amounts[i] == 1 
             ? singular_coin_names[i] 
             : plural_coin_names[i]
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and apologies for not commenting right away. Based on your responses i was able to fix it, thank you!

Also apologies it was my first post and i realize that i made mistakes posting it